Discord bot that will track who sent a screenshot in the thread
I made a BOT that's helping with our events in game.
Right now it does append list of users who reacted with thumbsup and post their names in the thread it's creating after being told (moneybag reaction added by message author).
People are supposed to send a screenshot in this thread AND add moneybag reaction to the PREVIOUS message. The point is that users usually forget to add that reaction and I'd like to remind them so:

BOT will inform whenever someone adds that reaction.
BOT would ping user after 20h with a message that they're missing reaction.

Here's the part of my code where bot:

doesn't let moneybag reaction if not skull reaction
filters message
append list of users who reacted with thumbsup
creates the thread
send users names in the thread

I'm not sure if I should make it (the part Id like to implement) for on_reaction_add or rather on_thread_create, maybe both? Can someone help me with this? I'm pretty new to python.
    if user == reaction.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "":
    channel = client.get_channel(1245389918361092126) #-payments

    moneybag_reaction = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.reactions, emoji='')
    skull_reaction = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.reactions, emoji='\U00002620\U0000fe0f')
    print("2")

    if not skull_reaction:
        print("3")
        await moneybag_reaction.remove(user)
        return


    mention_regex = re.compile(r"^<@&(\d+)> ")
    filtered_content = mention_regex.sub("", reaction.message.content, 1)
    print(filtered_content)
    message = await channel.send(f"{filtered_content} by {reaction.message.author.mention}")
    await message.add_reaction("")


    thumbsuplist = []
    message = reaction.message
    for reaction in message.reactions:
        print("2")
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            async for user in reaction.users():
                if user != client.user:
                    thumbsuplist.append(user.mention)
    joined = ", ".join(thumbsuplist)
    print(joined)



    thread_name = f"{filtered_content} by {reaction.message.author.display_name}"
    thread = await channel.create_thread(name=thread_name, auto_archive_duration=1440, reason=None, type=discord.ChannelType.public_thread)
    await thread.send(str(joined))


I don't see how on_thread_create can be used for this task. That event is only emitted upon the creation of a thread and you're trying to listen for users sending screenshots into the thread. If your game involves the users sending only the screenshot into the thread and nothing else then you can use on_thread_member_join instead, that way your bot can know whenever a user joins the thread (if the thread was joined by sending the screenshot). Then you can remind them to react by mentioning them/replying to them instantly (step 1) and set up a task to remind them in 20 hours again.
Here's a snippet showing how you can do it:
@client.listener
async def on_thread_member_join(member: discord.ThreadMember) -> None:
    # remind user to react
    await thread.send(f"<@{member.id}> remember to react to the previous message")

    # save the thread and member id somewhere to remind them later 

Alternatively, you can use on_reaction_add or on_raw_reaction_add. Use on_raw_reaction_add if your channels get a lot of messages as on_reaction_add is emitted only if the message is in the internal message cache.
For processing the reminders (in case of reminding 20h later), have a look at discord.ext.tasks, you can store the reminders in a db and run a loop to fetch and process those in a specified interval.

I cannot be sure people will send only SS. It may be SS + message or just a message. Screenshot is the requirement though.
Members of the thread are the ones collected for thumbsuplist in my code. They're joining upon thread creation 'cause bot pings everyone there.
That's why I thought if I can make more use of thumbsuplist and make the bot track who of this list has thumbsup and moneybag reaction and who doesn't.
